# Adding server (with port) to IIS web farm from command line

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, load-balancing, web-farm-framework

I have a web farm setup correctly with 7 servers on it, I used IIS Webfarm GUI to add these server. Now I want to use the command prompt because I have to add more then 50 servers and don't want to do that task manually. 
Following is the command to that I have seen working from command prompt but unfortuantly I am not able to find attribute for httpPort number.

```
 appcmd.exe set config  -section:webFarms /+"[name='myServerFarm'].[address='127.0.0.1']" /commit:apphost
```

I have tried this command with "port", "httpPort" attributes with no avail.

Can anyone please show me the command to add a server with HTTP port.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it with powershell and the Web Farm Framework cmdlets.

[Web Farm Framework Cmdlets](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/934/web-farm-framework-20-for-iis-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell/)

Look for the heading "Adding a Server to a Server Farm Using the cmdlets"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that worked for me:

> appcmd.exe set config -section:webFarms -[name='myServerFarm'].[address='127.0.0.1'].applicationRequestRouting.httpPort:8000